# Replacing print loops with list appends in python

Tags: python, refactoring, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to algorithmically change loops with print statements to list appends so that I can return them. There is no limit to the number of nested loops nor if there are if statements. For example, I have the code block:

```py
for i,elem in enumerate(container):
    for j in elem:
        if j!=i:
           print(j)
    print(i)
```

And I want to algorithmically change it to

```py
out = []
for i,elem in enumerate(container):
    for j in elem:
        if j!=i:
           out.append(str(j))
    out.append(str(i))
```

Is there a library that could potentially do this? I have seen both [refactor](https://github.com/isidentical/refactor) and [rope](https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/docs/overview.rst#restructurings) but they do not seem to do the job.

I know there is the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module but I would prefer not to make my own from scratch.

Comment: Maybe libCST could fit your use case? See the codemod feature: https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/codemods_tutorial.html

Comment: How is the program transformation supposed to know that the two `print` invocations use different arrays? Or are we to assume that every instance of `print` in your program has a different associated array? (And in that case, is it related to the textual location of the `print` statement, or the call frame in which the `print` statement executes?)

Comment: @rici Yea, the more I thought about it having a single out array would make more sense as all I care about is being able to turn this snippet into something that returns a list of what would have been printed. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: In that case, you could just redefine `print`.

Comment: @rici That seems like the best course, especially for certain cases. Would I need to redefine it in a subprocess when running the code?

Comment: @gorlan: define it in the globals dict you associate with the code you are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comprehension lists:

`out_2 = [str(j) for elem in container for j in elem if j!=i]`

And if you want to keep `out` list, simply do `out = list(range(container))`